# Django PDF: How to display progress in browser?

Tags: python, django, http, pdf, reportlab

The file will not display until the whole file is loaded. How can i display the  progress in browser?

```
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
     # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
     response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
     response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

     buffer = BytesIO()

     # Create the PDF object, using the BytesIO object as its "file."
     p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

     p.drawString(**, **, "Hello world.") # draw pdf, size > 10M

     # Close the PDF object cleanly.
     p.showPage()
     p.save()

     # Get the value of the BytesIO buffer and write it to the response.
     pdf = buffer.getvalue()
     buffer.close()
     response.write(pdf)
     return response
```

Comment: You mean that i guess how much time it takes by data size, and show the percent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your example I think it would be pretty simple (and almost instantaneous). You would just print out/return a progress indicator for `drawString`, `showPage`, etc. Assuming the actual PDF you're generating is more involved, you could use the `setProgressCallBack` method of the `BaseDocTemplate` class. Of course, this would require that you use the reportlab platypus engine.

There are a few methods/properties of note (see the comments), let's say you have a custom template class which overrides `BaseDocTemplate`:

```
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate

class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):
    """Override BaseDocTemplate for "progress bar" information"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        BaseDocTemplate.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # BaseDocTemplate keeps a "progress" dictionary for its own
        # internal use, which is updated as various drawings are done.
        # This directs reportlab to use your own custom method
        # as the "callback" function when updates are made.
        # Notice the use of the __ prefix for the method, which ensures
        # that it calls *your* custom class's method, and not the default.
        # Should match the signature of the original callback: (self, type, value)
        self.setProgressCallBack(self.__onProgress)

    def __onProgress(self, prog_type, value):
        """Progress monitoring"""

        # One example "progress type" is the "PAGE" key. Which indicates
        # which page reportlab is working on.
        if prog_type == "PAGE":
            print "Drawing page: %s" % value
        elif prog_type == "FINISHED":
            print "Drawing complete!"
```

Here are some more values (you can see the code in `reportlab.platypus.doctemplate`):

```
def progressCB(typ, value):
    """Example prototype for progress monitoring.

    This aims to provide info about what is going on
    during a big job.  It should enable, for example, a reasonably
    smooth progress bar to be drawn.  We design the argument
    signature to be predictable and conducive to programming in
    other (type safe) languages.  If set, this will be called
    repeatedly with pairs of values.  The first is a string
    indicating the type of call; the second is a numeric value.

    typ 'STARTING', value = 0
    typ 'SIZE_EST', value = numeric estimate of job size
    typ 'PASS', value = number of this rendering pass
    typ 'PROGRESS', value = number between 0 and SIZE_EST
    typ 'PAGE', value = page number of page
    type 'FINISHED', value = 0

    The sequence is
        STARTING - always called once
        SIZE_EST - always called once
        PROGRESS - called often
        PAGE - called often when page is emitted
        FINISHED - called when really, really finished

    some juggling is needed to accurately estimate numbers of
    pages in pageDrawing mode.

    NOTE: the SIZE_EST is a guess.  It is possible that the
    PROGRESS value may slightly exceed it, or may even step
    back a little on rare occasions.  The only way to be
    really accurate would be to do two passes, and I don't
    want to take that performance hit.
    """
    print 'PROGRESS MONITOR:  %-10s   %d' % (typ, value)
```